# Kentico tags with a custom page type

Tags: kentico

I'm reading through the documentation (https://docs.kentico.com/k9/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-tags/allowing-users-to-tag-pages-on-the-form-tab) and thought all was good, but when i go to create a new page based on the pate type, my Tag field is greyd out.

At the bottom of documentation page, is states:

> If you need to create a custom page type with a tag selector, the tag selector must be bound to a system field

I don't know what this means? I've created a tag group (Global), but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent page type has the Tag field in it already, the child page type will not allow you to change it, you have to go back to the parent page type to change any attributes about it.

Binding that tag selector to a system field means when you create that field, you need to select system field when you create it vs. a standard field.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've haven't implemented tags on this build, so i'm sure the parent node doesn't have any, but i'll double check. 

I did create the field as a Page Field, and then selected DocumentTags from the field name drop down, which is straight out of the documentation.

Comment: Ok that sounds correct, then make sure you the parent page has a tag group assigned to it.  Otherwise you wont' have any tags to assign.  The page needs the group in order to work properly.

Comment: Thanks Branden, I got it now. Cheers!